# How do I find out what makes a browser keep loading?

Tags: ajax, browser, opera

I am using Opera and sometimes a page keeps on loading even though all content has already been presented. How do I find out which elements are to be loaded or what causes the ongoing loading process?

Answer (score 0):

Even though all content seems to be 'presented', the page may still be loading images, JavaScript, CSS, or other resources referenced by it. This process performed by the browser isn't refereed to as "[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)" as you have tagged in your question. AJAX is the asynchronous invocation of JavaScript to retrieve or submit data without requiring page refreshes.

As for examining which resources are causing your page to appear to be still "loading"...

I use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)'s network tab to look at pending requests for resources in Firefox. It shows every resource your browser requests, how long it takes to retrieve, and the entire request & response headers and body.

Google chrome has something similar built-in, just hit F12 to bring up the "[Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)"

I would assume Opera has something similar although I am not sure of it's name.